# Scaling several floating images to fit width of parent container

Tags: css

I have a bootstrap-based website that contains several images of the same height next to each other, some floated to the left, some to the right:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="...">
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="...">
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

When the container is too narrow to fit all images in one row, they get stacked vertically, as is to be expected.

Now I'm looking for a possibility to resize these images simultaneously so they still fit horizontally and they keep the same height (and their respective ratio of course). I know I could use javascript, but I'm actually looking for a solution without it. Is that even possible?

Some additional information:

- The images are not necessarily the same width, just the same height
- There's a margin around each image and it's the same for each image. I don't care if the margin is applied to the `img` or the surrounding `div`
- Solutions can assume that the height and width of each image is known
- Also the number of images is known

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59rbv3yz/) to show the problem in its current state.

One final remark: This has sparked my curiosity, so although this is an actual problem I have, I'm also interested in solutions that lack browser-support or are otherwise not suitable for a live production page but might work at some point in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a flexbox solution:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: white;
}

.container div {
  padding: 1%;
}

.container img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The 1% padding on the `div` separates the images.  The `div`s are automatically scaled to the same height due to the flex model.

Setting the `img`s height and width to 100% causes them to fill their parent `div`s as well as maintain their height/width ratios.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx44zrv7/)**